# Regular expression for 8 to 10 letter words

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

I need a regular expression that matches either 8 letter words ending in "tion" or 10 letter words ending in "able".

Here is what I came up with, but for some reason http://regex101.com tells me there are no matches when I try to match a string.

My idea is as follows:

```
([a-z]{4}^\btion\b|[a-z]{6}^\bable\b)
```

Link to regex101 - [Here](https://regex101.com/r/dT6dK8/19)

Comment: I don't think you need the `^\b` before the `tion` or `able` suffixes. This should work: `\b([a-z]{4}tion|[a-z]{6}able)\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\b([a-z]{4}tion|[a-z]{6}able)\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT6dK8/20)

You use `^\b` between the variable section (e.g. `[a-z]{4}`) and constant postfix (e.g. `tion`) and that breaks the match. `^` means "beginning of the string (or a line)" and `\b` means "word boundary". Using it together makes little sense, as beginning of the string is always a word boundary.

Comment: You've been here for 7 years, you should know that "try this" is not a good explanation in an answer.

Comment: Well, regex tag is quite competitive. It's quite common to start with "try this" and provide explaination a bit later (in this case just 150s).

Comment: "matching "tion" and "able" just by typing them" what's wrong with that? How would you match exact substrings in other way that by typing them?

Answer (score 4):

`\b` matches a word boundary. You should only have this at the beginning and end of the word, not before the suffix. You can take it outside the grouping parentheses, since all the alternatives are supposed to match at word boundaries.

```
\b([a-z]{4}tion|[a-z]{6}able)\b
```

You don't need `^` at all, it matches the beginning of the string.